# Rails POST parameter with identical route parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route:

```
post ':client_name/login' => 'auth#log_in'
```

Client side I have a form with the following fields:

1. username
2. password
3. *and* client_name

I was hoping that the form data would override the route data so that I could change the client name if needed.  But it doesn't.  Any chance there's a setting for accessing that? Or a way to directly access *only* the post data?

F.y.i.: I don't show that <input> tag unless the user puts in the wrong password first.  In that case I provide it (already filled out with the value from the route).  This is helpful mainly for internal users who might get a link from one of their clients, they can then log in with a special value for the client that gives them more universal access.

Comment: On my very personal opinion, you shouldn't do it like this. You should have a more generic route

Comment: And yet I did...If it's impossible I won't (obviously).  Also, how?

Comment: why do you want to have this `client_name` prefix ? it would be much simpler to use a get or post param. Just use a route like `post :login => 'auth#login'`, and use path helpers like `login_path( :client_name => client_name )`. Your form will behave nicely with this.

Comment: @m_x not sure I understand you.  I want the client_name prefix because *different* clients authenticate differently.  I would love it to be as simple as authenticating identically, but every client has a different url I have to hit server-side, and one client (the internal one) has its own crazy schema.  Certainly not my design.  But it's the constraint I've been given.

Comment: You should do the `get` as `:username/login`. (the one who shows the login form). But do the form `post` to `/login`

Comment: @macool: if a person isn't logged in, I *can't* do the 'get' as `:username/login`

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl there, there. I know that feel, bro. So here's your problem : an html form needs an `action` attribute that is a fixed url, and your params are sent separately. If you really want to play with the url, you can use JS to update the action attribute of the form when your input changes. It's really ugly, but where you are i have a hunch that it won't make a difference.

Comment: Hmm. ok...so my form has no action attribute.  I'm relying on the fact that posting a form w/ no action posts to the current page's url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, until someone gives me a better solution (and I don't believe there is no better solution) I'll change the name of the posted client name to `:override_client_name`.